# SQL Query to get the vehicle ID and his locations to the most recent date(values distrubuted in 3 distinct tables)

Tags: sql

This is my first question here.
And I've been struggling for a while and I can't solve it.

So I want to get for all the circuits the location(latitude and longitude) to the most recent date.

The schema that I'm using contains important information so i will give an example:

```
table Circuit{
     NR int Primary Key,
     VEHICLE_ID int,
     etc...
}

table StopPoints{
     NR int Primary Key,
     Circuit int Foreign Key Circuit.NR,
     Latitude float,
     Longitude float,
     etc...
}

table StopPoint_Flux{
     NR int Primary Key,
     StopPoint int Foreign Key StopPoints.NR,
     Date DATE,
     etc...
}
```

And an example of the data in it:

Circuit:

| NR | VEHICLE_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 208 |
| 3 | 210 |
| 4 | 1 |

StopPoints:

| NR | Circuit | Latitude | Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0.3 | 5.0 |
| 2 | 1 | 1.7 | 8.0 |
| 3 | 2 | 7.0 | 10.0 |
| 4 | 4 | 11.0 | 1.2 |
| 5 | 3 | 45.0 | 46.0 |
| 6 | 4 | 43.1 | 6.23 |
| 7 | 1 | 34.42 | 36.98 |
| 8 | 3 | 40.48 | 47.50 |

StopPoint_Flux:

| NR | StopPoint | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 21/12/2020 |
| 2 | 2 | 19/12/2020 |
| 3 | 2 | 1/12/2020 |
| 4 | 1 | 5/12/2020 |
| 5 | 3 | 2/12/2020 |
| 6 | 5 | 7/12/2020 |
| 7 | 4 | 30/12/2020 |
| 8 | 5 | 7/12/2020 |
| 9 | 6 | 5/12/2020 |
| 10 | 8 | 1/12/2020 |
| 11 | 7 | 30/12/2020 |
| 12 | 6 | 8/12/2020 |
| 13 | 1 | 21/12/2020 |

The result that I need:

| VEHICLE_ID | Latitude | Longitude | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 34.42 | 36.98 | 30/12/2020 |
| 208 | 7.0 | 10.0 | 2/12/2020 |
| 210 | 45.0 | 46.0 | 7/12/2020 |
| 1 | 11.0 | 1.2 | 30/12/2020 |

Comment: I think you should use  RANK() OVER() in order to get the rank of the ordered descending data (in a temporary table). Then, filter by rank ==1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If ROW_NUMBER works.

```
SELECT 
  q.VEHICLE_ID
, q.Latitude
, q.Longitude
, q.Date
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
      circuit.VEHICLE_ID
    , stop.Latitude
    , stop.Longitude
    , flux.Date
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY circuit.NR
                         ORDER BY flux.Date DESC, stop.NR) AS rn
    FROM Circuit AS circuit
    JOIN StopPoints AS stop
      ON stop.circuit = circuit.NR
    JOIN StopPoint_Flux AS flux
      ON flux.StopPoint = stop.NR
) q
WHERE q.rn = 1
```

| vehicle_id | latitude | longitude | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 34.42 | 36.98 | 2020-12-30 |
| 208 | 7 | 10 | 2020-12-02 |
| 210 | 45 | 46 | 2020-12-07 |
| 1 | 11 | 1.2 | 2020-12-30 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=c308e7b5c01a366d8e1ba15d2c8591b7)*

Comment: @Falape Btw, you get different tudes if you change the order `ORDER BY flux.Date DESC, stop.NR DESC`. And you get tied stops if you use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY circuit.NR
                         ORDER BY flux.Date DESC) AS rn`